# Как передать значение из одного теста в другой? TestNG + Java

Tags: java, test-automation, testng

Задача такая: передать значение из одного теста в другой.
Пытаюсь сделать это с помощью ITestContext:

```
public class One {
    int waterfallId;

    @Test()
    public void testOne(ITestContext ctx) {
        /*код теста, инициализируется переменная waterfallId*/
        ctx.setAttribute("waterfallId", waterfallId);
    }

    @Test()
    public void testTwo(ITestContext ctx) {
        ctx.getAttribute("waterfallId"); //возвращает null
    }
}
```

Что не так?
Какие есть еще варианты решения?

Comment: Почему вам потребовалась передача значения in the first place?

Comment: @Etki, потому что я заранее не знаю значение этой переменной, а получаю ее в ходе выполнения теста

Comment: Тесты не должны зависеть друг от друга. К тому же порядок выполнения может быть разным — нет гарантии, что testTwo будет запускаться после testOne.

Лучше сделать получение данных отдельно либо в самом тесте, либо перед выполнением набора тестов.

Comment: @redL1ne похоже, что у вас на самом деле существует один тест, а не два

Answer (score -1):

Не так скорее всего то, что тесты идут в другом порядке.
Точно будет работать следующий способ:

1. сделать один тест зависимым от другого (dependsOn)
2. объявить поле в классе и в первом тесте что-то положить в этом поле, а во втором получить (т.к. TestNG создает один инстанс тестового класса, то это сработает, в отличие от JUnit)

   ```
   public class One {

    int waterfallId;

    @Test()
    public void testOne() {
      waterfallId=10;
    }

    @Test(dependsOn="testOne")
    public void testTwo() {
      System.out.println(waterfallId); // выведет 10
    }
   ```

   }